# Pandas - How to remove duplicates based on another series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

> I have a dataframe that contains three series called Date, Element,
>   and Data_Value--their types are string, string, and numpy.int64
>   respectively. Date has dates in the form of yyyy-mm-dd; Element has
>   strings that say either TMIN or TMAX, and it denotes whether the
>   Data_Value is the minimum or maximum temperature of a particular date;
>   lastly, the Data_Value series just represents the actual temperature.
>
> The date series has multiple duplicates of the same date. E.g. for the
>   date 2005-01-01, there are 19 entries for the temperature column, the
>   values start at 28 and go all the way up to 156. I want to create a
>   new dataframe with the date and the maximum temperature only--I'll
>   eventually want one for TMIN values too, but I figure that if I can do
>   one I can figure out the other. I'll post some psuedocode with
>   explanation below to show what I've tried so far.
>
> So far I have pulled in the csv and assigned it to a variable, df.
>   Then I sorted the values by Date, Element and Temperature
>   (Data_Value). After that, I created a variable called tmax that grabs
>   the necessary dates (I only need the data from 2005-2014) that have
>   'TMAX' as its Element value. I cast tmax into a new DataFrame, reset
>   its index to get rid of the useless index data from the first
>   dataframe, and dropped the 'Element' column since it was redundant at
>   this point. Now I'm (ultimately) trying to create a list of all the
>   Temperatures for TMAX so that I can plot it with pyplot. But I can't
>   figure out for the life of me how to reduce the dataframe to just the
>   single date and max value for that date. If I could just get that then
>   I could easily convert the series to a list and plot it.

```
    def record_high_and_low_temperatures():
        #read in csv
        df = pd.read_csv('somedata.csv') 

        #sort values so they're in a nice order
        df.sort_values(by=['Date', 'Element', 'Data_Value'], inplace=True) 

        # grab all entries for TMAX in correct date range
        tmax = df[(df['Element'] == 'TMAX') & (df['Date'].between("2005-01-01", "2014-12-31"))]

        # cast to dataframe
        tmax = pd.DataFrame(tmax, columns=['Date', 'Data_Value'])

        # Remove index column from previous dataframe
        tmax.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        # this is where I'm stuck, how do I get the max value per unique date? 
        max_temp_by_date = tmax.loc[tmax['Data_Value'].idxmax()]
```

Any and all help is appreciated, let me know if I need to clarify anything.

TL;DR:
Ok...
input dataframe looks like

```
date     | data_value
2005-01-01    28
2005-01-01    33
2005-01-01    33
2005-01-01    44
2005-01-01    56
2005-01-02    0
2005-01-02    12
2005-01-02    30
2005-01-02    28
2005-01-02    22
```

Expected df should look like:

```
date     | data_value
2005-01-01    79
2005-01-02    90
2005-01-03    88
2005-01-04    44
2005-01-05    63
```

I just want a dataframe that has each unique date coupled with the highest temperature on that day.

Comment: ```df.groupby("Date").max()``` you mean?

Comment: This might sound strange but I think you put too much there, it's overwhelming. A simple input df and expected output df is what we want to see. It's easier to help

Comment: @Kenan I added a TL;DR version. Let me know if that helps clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you would want to do is as Grzegorz already suggested in the comments, is to [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) date (take all elements of one date) and then take the maximum of that date:

```
df.groupby('date').max()
```

This will take all your groups and reduce them to only one row, taking the maximum element of every group. In this case, `max()` is called the aggregation function of the group. As you mentioned that you will also need the minimum at some point, a nice way to do this (instead of two groupbys) is to do the following:

```
df.groupby('date').agg(['max', 'min'])
```

which will pass over all groups once and apply both aggregation functions `max` and `min` returning two columns for each input column. More documentation on aggregation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

Comment: Even better, I like the sleekness! Thank you!

Comment: @Moose With `pandas` integrated plotting functionality you can even do `a.groupby('a').agg(['max', 'min']).plot()` to then plot both at the same time. Just make sure to import pyplot (`import matplotlib.pylot as plt`) and then add `plt.show()` afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby("Date")['data_value'].max()
```